# Как в консоль WordPress добавить кнопку?

Tags: wordpress

Хочу понять как добавить кнопку в консоль, а именно кнопку Фильмы, что бы через нее добавлять фильмы, описание, рейтинг, год и т.д и создавать жанр. подскажите, где я могу найти достаточно информации об этом, а то уже надежду теряю.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То что вам нужно это Custom Post Types - Произвольные типы записей. Почитать об этом можно в статьях

- [Типы постов в WordPress. Добавление собственных произвольных типов
  постов.](http://truemisha.ru/blog/wordpress/post-types.html)
- [Что такое Custom Post Types?](https://wpcafe.org/tutorials/rukovodstvo-po-kastomnyim-tipam-zapisey-wordpress/)

Comment: спасибо тебе большое, очень помог!